# Error al Intentar subir mi proyecto a Git Hub

Tags: git, github

Lo que quiero realizar es subir el proceso de un proyecto que tengo a mi github pero al momento de hacerlo por medio de cmd me marca un error que no eh logrado resolver.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se a que se deba ese error y es que no consigo hacer que mi proyecto se mantenga en el gitHub

Comment: Creaste primero el proyecto en tu perfil de github o lo creaste desde consola?

Comment: Lo cree desde mi perfil de github

Comment: Gracias, si era eso solo que debía de poner git pull origin master y después el push, si quieres pon la respuesta para ponerla como buena

Comment: dale tu voto ha equiso que te respondio

Comment: ya lo hice, voto y afirmación correcta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En el mensaje te dice que hagas `pull` primero, seguramente hay cambios en el repositorio remoto que no tienes en el local. Intenta con `git pull` antes de volver a usar `git push`.

Answer (score -1):

**Crea tu proyecto en github en la plataforma luego sigue los pasos
Sigue esos pasos en caso de que te siga dando error elimina la carpeta git init y vuelve hacer el proceso.**

Comandos para github subir proyectos

```
    git init
    git remote -v
    git remote add origin link-del-proyecto-git
    git add .
    git add --all
    git commit -m"Proyecto Final"
    git push -u origin master
    git push --force origin master
```